# Can't choose option on gcloud signup form using selenium by python?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, xpath, element

i want to automate google cloud signup form but cant do this by selenium because i m unable to find the element for choosing option
[Required option to Choose](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yk0os.jpg)

```
bus= driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='goog-inline-block goog-flat-menu-button-caption']//div[@class = 'goog-menuitem-content']")
```

print(bus)

[code in which it throws exception that we can't find the element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FJR6F.jpg)

as mentioned in pictures when we find the xpath in chrome it shows 1 of 1
but when we find in code by xpath its gives error

target site:https://console.cloud.google.com/freetrial/signup/billing/PK?pli=1

Comment: What exact option are you trying to select here? Business or individual account types are applied by default so you don't often to get to make that choice i.e. your google account decides that automatically. maybe when you are running with selenium you may need to activate your profile to ensure that it applied the correct account type.

Comment: its signup form so we have to select the account type but by the selenium